# VB - How to get datagridview column to auto-format color?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview

My DataGridView have some columns I want to turn a different color to indicate that they are auto-fill columns and does not need user input.

So I created the code to color columns:

```
Private Sub autocolumn()

    Dim auto_cell As New DataGridViewCellStyle
    auto_cell.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue
    ProjTable.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle = auto_cell
    ProjTable.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle = auto_cell
    ProjTable.Columns(9).DefaultCellStyle = auto_cell
    ProjTable.Columns(10).DefaultCellStyle = auto_cell

End Sub
```

And then place it into form Load event

```
Private Sub projectentry_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    autocolumn()

End Sub
```

On testing the form, the first row is colored no problem. Issue is on the 2nd row the color is  white. Then the 3rd row its colored, and thee following white. And it follows this repeated pattern.

I even tried to make a DataGridView Rows Added event to call the sub

```
Private Sub color_load() Handles ProjTable.RowsAdded

    autocolumn()

End Sub
```

Again same result. What may be the problem here?

Comment: There must be something else going on that you are not providing. The posted code appears to work as expected. In my tests, the columns were colored as expected with no gaps between rows. I placed the `autocolumn` method in the forms `Load` event, in addition to the grids `RowsAdded` event (which is unnecessary) and the columns were colored properly. Can you post the code that reproduces the issue you describe?

Comment: What I showed is all I have related to color format. The rest is SQL which is not related. However I did check the `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` and see that it defaulted to white.

Comment: But  I keep removing it but it still stays as white. Which is weird.

Comment: Ok. The last try to remove it finally works. Now the display works fine.